# Can I connect local sql server database as source in AWS SCT?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration, aws-dms, aws-sct

I want to connect my local sql server database as source in SCT to convert it to Amazon RDS for MySQL. After Im planning to use DMS for the migration task.

Comment: Probably easier to just try this??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. per the product https://aws.amazon.com/dms/

[Start here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_SchemaConversionTool.GettingStarted.Source.SQLServer.html)

> Your source database can be on-premises, or in Amazon RDS or EC2 and
>   the target database can be in either Amazon RDS or EC2. The AWS Schema
>   Conversion Tool supports the following conversions.

Source Database  ---->  Target Database on Amazon RDS

Microsoft SQL Server ---->  Amazon Aurora, Amazon Redshift, MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB